# How can I change opacity of first listview element?

Tags: c#, listview, windows-8

im trying to change opacity of first ListView element,
 but i am not getting the right way to implemet it ;
 Can you please give some suggestions ?

```
display.Opacity = 0.5;
                foreach (Common trigger in display.Items)
                {
                    if (trigger.Image_Name == "First")
                    {
                        trigger.Opacity = 1;
                    }
                }
```

where display is my ListView

Comment: You need to show an example of what you have tried so far, otherwise you wont get any answers

Comment: I tried in many ways ... but i don't know how to do this , in first post my last try

Answer (score 1):

When you change the opacity property of ListView it does not affect to it's items separately(opacity changes for ListView as a whole). If you want to set all items opacity to 0.5 except one, try to do something like this

```
for(int i=1; i<display.Items.Count;i++)
  display.Items[i].Opacity = 0.5;
```

Comment: I cant use Opacity with display.Items[i] ... Can you tell me why ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Items elements has `object` type, so you need to cast it to your items type or to UIElement:`(display.Items[i] as UIElement).Opacity`

Comment: it's still not working but thank - now im closer to find the answer :)

Comment: Did you remove `display.Opacity = 0.5;`?

Comment: Now i have sth like that : 

display.Opacity = 0.5;
var uiElement = display.Items[2] as UIElement;
if (uiElement != null) uiElement.Opacity = 1;

and every element is 0.5 opacity ;/

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.opacity(v=vs.110).aspx :Opacity is applied from parent elements on down the element tree to child elements, but the visible effects of the nested opacity settings aren't indicated in the property value of individual child elements. For instance, if a list has a 50% (0.5) opacity and one of its list items has its own opacity set to 20% (0.2), the net visible opacity for that list item will be rendered as if it were 10% (0.1), but the property value of the list item Opacity property would still be 0.2 when queried.