# How to change the opacity of custom elements of ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, windows-8.1

I have list view and I want to set `opacity` of some elements, but unfortunatelly setting `opacity` on `ListViewItem` just don't work...

```
<Style x:Name="TileStyle" TargetType="ListView">
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Width="185"
                          Height="85"
                          Margin="20"
                          Background="Red"
                          Opacity="0.1">
                        <TextBlock Text="fasada" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

---

```
   <ListView x:Name="XListView"
          ItemsSource="{Binding li}"
          Style="{StaticResource TileStyle}" />
```

It's working only when I set one opacity for `ListView` object.

I've found [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993912/how-can-i-change-opacity-of-first-listview-element) describing similar problem, but `XListView.Items[i]` is just int, so I can't set its `Opacity`...

### Update

I forgot to say that this is program for `Windows-8.1`, so some `WPF` properties could be unsupported.

Comment: If you are using MVVM architecture, why don't you bind it to some property of your model.

Comment: Do you mean binding Opacity with somoe property? It's the same problem, which i mentioned at the begining (it's just don't work).

Comment: Read user3449857 answer. That's what'm taking about.

Answer (score 0):

Lukasz here :-)

To successfully apply opacity to your `ListViewItem` you will need something like this

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ListViewItem}" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1.0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Border Name="Border" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="Transparent" CornerRadius="15">
                        <GridViewRowPresenter VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundBrush}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.4"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Give it a go and let us know.
HTH

**UPDATE**

After seeing new info you will need

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ListViewItem}" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="{Binding VM.Property}"/>
    </Style>
```

Although this will require every item in the list to define the opacity.
*You can always use fallbackValue to use default opacity = 1.0*

Comment: Hi, thanks for response, triggers are good idea, but unfortunately it's not supported in Windows8.1

Comment: @JakubKuszneruk have you had any luck with my update?

Answer (score 0):

Just for example.
View model for item:

```
public class Item
{
    public double Opacity {get;set;}
    public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

ListView xaml code:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="{Binding Opacity}" />
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Value}" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

If you want to change opacity in runtime, you should implement [INotifyProperyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) for your `Item` class.

Comment: I don't need `INotifyPropertyChanged`, I want to initialize `ListView` with objects with different capacity. I did what you've written and I've added Background, but it still don't work (element with opacity 0.1 looks the same like the one with opacity equals 0.9).
My solution http://1drv.ms/1fEJEpa

Comment: Sorry. Cannot help you, after watching your code I mentioned that it's **Windows Store Application**. I don't even have Windows 8.1 to do some tests. Hope you will find answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am considering you want to change opacity of listview element i.e listviewitem so you need to change listviewitem style i.e Listview Itemcontainerstyle and by editing template of listview item you can set opacity to element.I am using grid to display 3 workaround for listviewitem style.Hope this helps

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!--****************************1st method*******************************-->
    <ListView x:Name="XListView" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding li}" >
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Grid Width="185" Height="85" Margin="20" Background="Red" Opacity="0.1">
                                <TextBlock Text="TextData"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListViewItem>ListviewItemData1</ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
    <!--**************************2nd method***********************************-->
    <ListView  Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding li}" >
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" >
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Width="185" Height="85" Margin="20" Background="Red" Opacity="0.1">
                                <TextBlock Text="TextData"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListViewItem>ListviewItemData1</ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
    <!--*****************3rd method*****************-->
    <ListView Grid.Column="2">
        <ListViewItem >
            <ListViewItem.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Grid Width="185" Height="85" Margin="20" Background="Red" Opacity="0.1">
                        <TextBlock Text="TextData"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ListViewItem.Template>
        </ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

You can set opacity like this also

```
 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RedBrush" Color="Red" Opacity="0.1"></SolidColorBrush>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Page.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="tootStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.1"/>
        </Style>
</Page.Resources>


<ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource tootStyle}">
            <ListViewItem Background="red">AZERTY</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem Background="Green">AZERTY</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem Background="Blue">AZERTY</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem Background="Purple">AZERTY</ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```